# Application insight monitor doesn't send data to portal due to insufficient permission

Tags: azure-application-insights

I installed the application insight status monitor on IIS, however I still don't have server data on the azure portal, and in the monitor I got the following warning message on my app.

"The application XXX running under application pool 'XXX' might have insufficient permissions to collect performance data. If no performance counter data is visible in the portal, make sure that the security principal under which the application runs is a member of 'Performance Monitor Users' group".

Where can I set up the security principal of my app? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the identity under which your Application Pool is running doesn't have access to monitoring and collecting performance counter data. To fix this, you could do the following:

1. Determine the identity of the Application Pool in IIS

   - Open `inetmgr` using Run or directly launch IIS from Windows
   - Click on **Application Pools** and check the identity for the app pool running your app.
   - Alternatively you could navigate to the application, click on Basic or Advanced Settings and check the Application Pool
   - The application pool identity might be set to a built-in one, such as LocalServer, LocalSystem etc. or a custom account.
2. Add this identity to 'Performance Monitor Users' Group

   - Open Users and Groups or directly launch `lusrmgr.msc` from Run
   - Navigate to Groups -> Performance Monitor Users
   - Add the identity of the application pool (from previous step)

Now your app should be able to collect performance counters and also send to AI without any problems.

Hope this helps!