# Azure App service - User has insufficient permissions to collect Windows Performance Counters

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-performancecounters

We have hosted a .Net application as an Azure App Service. I am trying to install an APM called New Relic. I am stuck at this error.

`The executing user, IIS APPPOOL\XXX, has insufficient permissions to collect Windows Performance Counters.`

I understand how this can be handled in a VM with access to IIS [Application insight monitor doesn't send data to portal due to insufficient permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124901/application-insight-monitor-doesnt-send-data-to-portal-due-to-insufficient-perm)

I also didn't find any setting via Azure KUDU console.

However, I am trying to find how to setup "Users and Groups" in an **Azure App Service** Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow standard procedures to [update the .NET agent](https://docs.newrelic.co.jp/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/net-release-notes) to  **8.18.241.0**.

For .NET Framework it will **fix an issue where a large number of error messages may be reported on agent startup due to insufficient permissions of the app-pool user to create performance counters**. In this release, a specific warning message regarding permissions will be reported.

If you are upgrading from a particularly old agent, review the list of major changes and procedures to [upgrade legacy .NET agents](https://docs.newrelic.co.jp/docs/agents/net-agent/installation/update-net-agent).

Comment: thanks for checking that. But I have installed a higher version 8.21.34 for which I am still getting this issue.

Comment: Have you check whether 8.18.241 version is ok to avoid no backward compatibility.